# Sharepoint: How to include a tasklist from a subsite in a wiki page

Tags: 2010, task-list, cross-site

I have a site hierarchy that looks like:

- Roadmaps (/engineering/roadmaps)

  - RM1 Meeting Site (/engineering/roadmaps/RM1Meet)
  - RM2 Meeting Site (/engineering/roadmaps/RM2Meet)

Now those meeting subsites are how the teams that write the roadmaps track their tasks. You know, in the task lists on those subsites (for example, /engineering/roadmaps/RM1Meet/Lists/Tasks/AllItems.aspx).

The parent Roadmaps site has a set of wikipages (RM1wiki, RM2wiki) that are the actual roadmaps for various things. For example, /engineering/roadmaps/sitepages/RM1wiki.aspx

What I want to do is out on the wikipage for the roadmap is have the tasklist appear as a webpart drawing its data from the list on the subsite.

```
Wiki Page       -> /engineering/roadmaps/sitepages/RM1wiki.aspx
List on subsite -> /engineering/roadmaps/RM1Meet/Lists/Tasks/AllItems.aspx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is the same question as [SharePoint2010 view tasks list items from child sites](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8033/sharepoint-2010-view-tasks-list-items-from-child-sites).  There's a suggestion there to use the [Content by Query Web Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241.aspx).  I took that for a road test and it seems to work okay.